# Level in SQL Server and start with

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, levels

I have a problem with a query in SQL Server.

I have this query in ORACLE SQL.

```
select 
    LEVEL, serial_number, table_, position, description, article, next_table, root_table 
from
    bill_of_material 
where 
    serial_number = ABC.123.ZXC  
start with table_ = root_table
connect by prior next_table=table_
order by level, table_, position
```

I need to get the same query in SQL Server.

This query works with the level, the data are in a lot of record and I need a tree with different level.

Can every body help me please?

best regards

Alessandro

Comment: youll have to do a hierarchy in sql server with a different method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641543/recursive-cte-sql-with-for-hierarchy-level

Comment: `CONNECT BY` is ORacle-specific. You can achieve the same effect using a recursive CTE. A better idea would be to use a [hierarchyid](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-2017) field instead of connection parent and child IDs, or table names as you do here. A `hierarchyID` is similar to a library code which means hierarchy searches are essentially range searchs that can be accelerated by indexes. To get the level of a record all you need is to call `node.GetLevel()` where  `node` is the name of the hierarchy field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate this into a recursive common table expression:

```
with rcte(level, serial_number, table_, position, description, article, next_table, root_table)
as (
  select 1, serial_number, table_, position, description, article, next_table, root_table
    from bill_of_material
   where serial_number = ABC.123.ZXC
     -- Start with
     and table_ = root_table
  union all
  select prev.level+1
       , curr.serial_number
       , curr.table_
       , curr.position
       , curr.description
       , curr.article
       , curr.next_table
       , curr.root_table
    from rcte prev
    join bill_of_material curr
      on prev.next_table = curr.table_
)
select * from rcte
 order by level, table_, position
```